# Excel VBA: selecting a range of cells in columns based on a values in each row in a different column

Tags: excel, vba

I have 6 columns (named A - E for the first 5 columns and ID for column 6) with flags 1 through 5 in the first 5 columns (so each column either has a flag or zero) and an ID number in column 6. I would like to make a loop to look in each row and pull the flag column and the ID column based on the value set by me. So for example, I would like to look in Column A (where there are 1s and 0s) and pull ID numbers from column ID where the value in column A is 1. I would like to go through the column A, select and copy 1s and corresponding values from column ID and paste it into another tab.

I am able to either select a value in column ID based on a value in column A and paste it into another tab, but unable to select values in both columns.

```
Sub CopyPaste()
    Dim TheSheet As Worksheet
    If TypeOf ActiveSheet Is Worksheet Then
        Set TheSheet = ActiveSheet
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim Row As Integer
    Dim CellsToSelect As String
    For Row = 4 To TheSheet.Range("A" & CStr(TheSheet.Rows.Count)).End(xlUp).Row
        If TheSheet.Range("A" & CStr(Row)).Value = 1 Then
            If CellsToSelect <> "" Then CellsToSelect = CellsToSelect & ","
            CellsToSelect = CellsToSelect & "F" & CStr(Row)
        End If
    Next Row
    TheSheet.Range(CellsToSelect).Select

    With Selection.Copy
    Worksheets("Summary").Activate
    b = Worksheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("Summary").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    End With
End Sub
```

If I can look through rows in column 1 and find say 0, then select column 1 and column 6 for each row where column 1 = 0, and then paste it into a separate tab, I can then loop it for the other columns I have. Greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Have You thought about filtering and copying visible cells to another tab?

Comment: I have - the problem is that I need to filter all of the first 5 columns and I can't do them simultaneously. Therefore I would like to look through each column, select, copy and paste data to another tab. Go through all of the columns and append filtered data to this new tab where I will do additional calcs. I hope that makes sense.